# Fix a html table with a specific style

Tags: html, css

I have the following css bit

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
}
```

and i need to create the following style page with html:

[image]

how can i achieve it?

here is my attempt:

```
<table>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You may look into the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes.

Comment: look on grid-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td colspan="2">2</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">2</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I think the structure it is a bit wrong and also you should use `colspan` and `rowspan` for TDs. I added some css too.

Comment: your Table miss the first tr-Tag ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A little too late. And @NicolaeMaties has already right answeared. The way is simply via col and rowspan. the numbering helps you to understand this better. The principle is then also easy to understand: `colspan="howManyColsMerged"` and `rowlspan="howManyRowsMerged"`.

```css
td {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```